# Sharing a template with identical category and tag name

Tags: entries, templating, tags, categories

I'm trying to stay as DRY as possible here and sharing one template for a news list view; all, category and tag all sharing the same template (and trying to refrain from having a category or tag segment). My query isn't returning any results when the segment 2 (in this case the url encoded tag or category slug) when there is a tag and category that share the same name. Example, 'design' is a category for design related posts; 'design' is a tag for posts that featured a design service within the 'portfolio' category. My template code is below. Is there a work around here or do I need to have a second segment for tag/category (i.e. `.com/news/category/design` and `.com/news/tag/design` - or one or the other to differentialte)

```
{% if category is defined %}

    {% set newsPosts = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(category).limit(5) %}

{% elseif tag is defined %}

    {% set tag = craft.tags.groupId(3).name(tag).first() %}

    {% set newsPosts = craft.entries.section('news').relatedTo(tag).limit(5) %}

{% else %}

    {% set newsPosts = craft.entries.section('news').limit(5) %}

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Marion's post is right, it's not quite what I was trying to achieve I didn't want to have 2 templates (although use of macros is perfectly suitable).

What I've done to get around this is is add a `tag` segment for tags and leave categories as is. Then I added a custom route to support the tag segement but use the same template code

**URI's:**

`/news/*category*`

`/news/tag/*tag*`

The category route is defined automagically, but I needed to set up a route for the `tag` view.

**Template Path:**

`news/index` (which is also defined as my Category Template in the category settings)

Using the same template code above, I'm able to get the index/list view of a `category` and `tag` when they are the same all within the same template.

Answer (score 2):

If the url for posts with the **category** `design` is `.com/news/design` and the url for posts with the **tag** `design` is also `.com/news/design`, then you are not going to be able to see both lists. You do need that extra segment in the url.

What I do to stay DRY is let Craft route tags and categories to different templates (so you don't have to repeat the *is this a category or a tag* logic). Then on the different templates, use a [macro](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) or [include](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) for the common code.

Here is what the categories page looks like with a macro:

```
{% extends '_layout' %}
{% import '_macros/_news' as news %}

{% set newsPosts = craft.entries.section('news')relatedTo(category).limit(5) %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Entries with category {{category.title}}</h1>
  {{ news.index(newsPosts) }} {# all the shared code is in news.index() #}
{% endblock content %}
```